# How can I read a file containing text and image data?

Tags: java, image, file, text, bufferedreader

I've got a file with the following structure:

```
<number>
<title>
<text>
<image data>
```

For example:

```
176
Elephant
This image shows a cute elephant.
<image data bytes go here>
```

I write the example above like this:

```
String filepath = "myfile.txt";
BufferedImage image = ...; //load some image here

try(FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filepath)))
{
    writer.write("Number: 176");
    writer.newLine();
    writer.write("Title: Elephant");
    writer.newLine();
    writer.write("Text: This image shows a cute elephant.");
    writer.newLine();

    ImageIO.write(image, "png", output);

    writer.flush();
}
catch (Exception) {//exception handling}
```

This works fine. However, I do not know how to read the file.
The problem is that I need to call ImageIO.read() to parse the image, but I can't call it with a BufferedReader. My draft looks like this:

```
String filepath = "myfile.txt";

try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader(filepath)))
{
    String number = reader.readLine();
    reader.readLine(); //skip a free line

    String title = reader.readLine();
    reader.readLine(); //skip a free line

    String text = reader.readLine();
    reader.readLine(); //skip a free line

    BufferedImage image = ???; //how can I read the image here? <----------------

}
catch (Exception e) {//error handling ...}
```

**So: How can I read the image (using ImageIO)?**

Any help is very appreciated :)

---

**EDIT: Like  I do the writing with two different Writers, is it possible to make use of two Readers while reading? Like "Read 3 lines of Strings, then read one line of binary data".**

Comment: How is the image data formatted?  Is it represented in binary form or Base64?

Comment: It is represented in binary form. 
(I load a PNG image file with ImageIO.read, store it into a BufferedImage and write it with ImageIO.write)

Comment: If the image data is mixed in with other data, then you need to read that binary data into another stream input stream so that it can be read correctly from the file.  You "might" be able to use the same `InputStream` you read the file and simply read to the start of the image data...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I understand and appreciate your idea, but maybe actual code would help me a lot :)

Comment: @Loc I didn't downvote your question :O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, as I can see it, is the mixing of the readers and streams..

Now, I tried using...

```
try (OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output))) {
    
    writer.write("Number: 176");
    writer.newLine();
    writer.write("Title: Elephant");
    writer.newLine();
    writer.write("Text: This image shows a cute elephant.");
    writer.newLine();

    writer.flush();

    ImageIO.write(image, "png", output);

    output.flush();
} catch (Exception exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

To write the file.  The hope was that the input stream position would be updated and the content would be written to the end of the file...

And

```
String filepath = "myfile.txt";
BufferedImage image = null;
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(filepath));
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) {
    
    String number = br.readLine();
    String title = br.readLine();
    String text = br.readLine();
    
    System.out.println(number);
    System.out.println(title);
    System.out.println(text);

    ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(is);
    image = ImageIO.read(iis);
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("test.png"));
} catch (Exception exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

To read it.

But this didn't seem to work.  What "might" be happening is the file position isn't being updated to the correct position that we need it to read the image properly.

What I did instead was this...

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;

public class ReadWriteImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            writeTest();
            readTest();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void readTest() throws IOException {
        String filepath = "myfile.txt";
        BufferedImage image = null;
        try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(filepath))) {
        
            int lineCount = 0;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);
        
            String number = null;
            String title = null;
            String text = null;
        
            int b = -1;
            while (lineCount < 3 && (b = is.read()) != -1) {
                if ((char)b == '\n') {
                    switch (lineCount) {
                        case 0:
                            number = sb.toString();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            title = sb.toString();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            text = sb.toString();
                            break;
                    }
                    sb.delete(0, sb.length());
                    lineCount++;
                } else {
                    sb.append((char)b);
                }
            }
        
            System.out.println(number);
            System.out.println(title);
            System.out.println(text);

            ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(is);
            image = ImageIO.read(iis);
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("test.png"));
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void writeTest() throws IOException {
        String filepath = "myfile.txt";
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/swhitehead/Dropbox/MegaTokyo/thumnails/2005-09-29-3957_400.jpg"));

        try (FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(filepath)) {
        
            output.write("Number: 176\n".getBytes());
            output.write("Title: Elephant\n".getBytes());
            output.write("Text: This image shows a cute elephant.\n".getBytes());

            ImageIO.write(image, "png", output);

            output.flush();
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Basically, I just used the `OutputStream` and `InputStream` directly...

**Updated**

The file contents starts with...

```
Number: 176
Title: Elephant
Text: This image shows a cute elephant.
âPNG
```

## Welcome to 2021

So, the ordinal answer was made some time ago, the world has moved on.  Unless you have a very specific need not to (ie transport speed/bandwidth restrictions), I would highly recommend making use of things like JSON and Base64 to send binary and text mixed together.

The main reason, it's actually much simpler to encode/decode and maintain.  The original solution is rather difficult to add new content to, as both ends need to be able to support the changes, where as something like JSON can (if done properly) get away with adding and removing content.  It's also easier to build much more complex parsing workflows, as you're not reliant on the "read/write" position of the stream.

This example makes use of the [org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) library, but you can use what ever library you want.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() throws IOException {
        read(write());
    }

    public String write() throws IOException {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/Background.png"));

        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
        jobj.put("number", 176);
        jobj.put("title", "Elephant");
        jobj.put("text", "This image shows a cute elepant");

        try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
            baos.flush();
            byte[] encode = Base64.getEncoder().encode(baos.toByteArray());
            String text = new String(encode, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            jobj.put("image", text);
        }

        String text = jobj.toString();

        return text;
    }

    public void read(String jsonText) throws IOException {
        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonText);
        System.out.println("Number = " + jobj.getInt("number"));
        System.out.println("Title = " + jobj.getString("title"));
        System.out.println("Text = " + jobj.getString("text"));

        String encodedImage = jobj.getString("image");
        byte[] imageBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedImage.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        try (ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes)) {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(bais);

            JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
            label.setText("<html>Number = " + jobj.getInt("number") + "<br>Title = " + jobj.getString("title") + "<br>Text = " + jobj.getString("text"));

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, label);
        }
    }

}
```

> What if I want to send 2 files?

Then use a `JSONArray`. `org.json` is reasonably powerful, see [Introduction to JSON-Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-org-json)  for more details.  The Google implementation (GSON?) also provides a lot of functionality which can be used to encode/decode json from/to POJOs, if that's your thing

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) I read your code, understood it and saw that it works exactly the way I hoped. Now, I can adapt it to my needs and optimize performance (e.g. using read(byte[]) instead of read()).

My personal lesson is: Never mix reading or writing with readers and streams. Thanks again for your efforts.

Comment: @Loc
Yeah, but that's perfectly fine :) Messing around with the FileWriter in my first example was just an approach to get he idea in my head running as code. In the end, there's no problem using binary format (or is there?).

Comment: No problem. It works, I know it. I only thought you wanted use TEXTUAL format ( your file extension is .txt)

Comment: @loc Try the example and open the file in a text editor, you should be able to read the text before the binary content. Personally, I agree, it would be better to use base64 encoding, maybe even using XML as the base format...but this gets the OP over the line...

Comment: Even it is binary, you still view its content using a text editor. Is that right?

Comment: I didn't say NOT. But in your code, when you write the content, you used write ( bytes ). This means you used binary format.

Comment: @loc `OutputStream` only provides `byte[]` or `int` output.  The only choice was to use `String#getBytes`.  See update for example ;)

Comment: @ MadProgrammer
You said you'd prefer base64 encoding - why is that so? I my prior file format, I had base64 encoding. 

A large number of files in the given format have to be processed, and having the images base64'd a) increases the file size and b) takes more time to load, since the base64 String needs to be decoded first. Also, it will use more memory.

Comment: @Above Basically, it's easier to transport, easier to manage and simpler to extract. Again, if wrap the whole thing in a XML format to make it easier to pick elements out. Mixing binary and text data is just messy, IMHO. If size is an issue, you could always compress the file ;)

Comment: Ignore Base64 and XML advice it adds complexity and takes more time and space for doing something that is very simple, I mean people did just fine before XML was invented and infected the Java language with all its problems. Saying that text is easier to transport is FUD, from the days when systems only send 7 bit ASCII ( like Usenet ) this hasn't been the case in general computing in decades. Don't use Bas64 and you don't have a "extract" anything it is in its native format. Wrapping encoded binaries in XML is just more waste of time and space and added code and complexity.

Comment: What if I want to send 2 files?

Comment: @lcj Why is that any different then sending a single file

Comment: @user177800 To true, we should all drop these dumb high level languages and concepts and go back to assembly!  Mixing text and data isn't "hard", if you design your solution to support it, but if your end point only supports ascii based text, for example, then using things like base64 will save your live, I'm just saying.  There are gently of ways to solve the problem, this is just one of them

Comment: @user177800  Using something like base64 makes the read/write process "generally" simpler (rather then having the need for lots of markers or command sequences), which is where things like XML or JSON come into play - you send a single "data dump" in a self contained unit of work, no need for complex, error prone, custom parsing.  The only reason I would consider not doing something like that would be if the connection speed was very slow

Comment: Based on the procedure above you can’t send two files. The switch statement and the count reserves the file for the last part of the stream. Given that ‘\n’ = 10 which could be a part of the file, it can’t be used to identify even one file ends and the other begins.

Comment: @lcj So, based on the above, how do you think you would modify so that you could reset the line count after each image is read/written?  Since you're saying you want to send two files, why not close the writer/read between each file?

Comment: I would create an index taking up the first x bytes (maybe with some room for upgrades in case sender and receiver have different software versions). The index would give me start and length for each value I was pulling. That means I need to allocate the right numbers from the bytes and package up the index before I send the value. I think. Never really done this type of thing before.

Comment: @lcj Also look at the update I did, which one of those two workflows do you think would be simpler and easy to use and maintain?

Comment: Yeah. That looks easier. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

#### Approach given your example:

This simple, if you only have 3 lines of text as listed in your example, then you can just read each line of `Text` when you detect the `\n`, when you get to the third one you know the image data is next and then just read from that offset into your image.

A better way to do it is to write a simple index header first with the offset of the `binary` data and then you don't have to do the parsing of the `\n` you can just read up to the offset and treat all that as text and then read from the offset on and treat the rest as your image.

There is no reason you need to encode anything to Base64 or anything like that, that will just bloat your file format and cause more complication than good.

Comment: This sounds exactly like what I tried to do. But could you please show in code how I "just read from that offset into your image"? 
(With that, I mean: What do I have to write in the line where the "BufferedImage image = ???" is now?)

Comment: Not convert everything to base64. Image only. Because Above want to use TEXT format so we have to do like this. If he want to use BINARY format, we don't have to convert Image to base64 string.

Comment: Everything you need to do this is in the JavaDoc, try something and then ask how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work, but as @MadProgrammer said, use the same reader from the BufferedReader initialization in the ImageIO.read call:

```
Reader fileReader = new FileReader(...);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
...
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(fileReader);
```

Or, with FileReader(FileInputStream)... after all, you are doing something very similar when writting. Lesson here to be learned: symmetry always helps in situations like this.